# How can I set a quota in /etc/fstab?

Tags: disk, quota

I want to mount my /home in /etc/fstab for quota limits how do I do that?

My Ubuntu-Server fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

#### UPDATE

@Rinzwind

fstab

```
home /home ext4 defaults,usrquota 0 0 
mount -o remount /home
```

---

```
root@ubuntu:/home/one# mount -o remount /home
mount: /home not mounted already, or bad option
```

After Rebooting:

[image: error "Filesystem could not be mounted: /home"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `,usrquota` to the options of the partition that your created for this. 
A possible(!) valid method would be:

```
home /home ext4 defaults,usrquota 0 0
```

but since you do not have a partition with mount point home I am just guessing. After that you need to remount `/home`.

```
mount -o remount /home
```

and the filesystem then knows it needs to check for quota (ie. `/home/aquota.user`).

Comment: what will be entries in fstab , plz update

Comment: home                            /home        ext4           defaults,usrquota,grpquota   0       0 ?